# I cannot record video at 60fps using camerax api

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

Using CameraX or Camera2 I can not record videos at 60fps in My SamsungS10 which actually supports recording UHD videos with 60fps using Samsung Camera App. I can only record at 30fps!

Here is my code

```
QualitySelector qualitySelector = QualitySelector.fromOrderedList(
                        Arrays.asList(Quality.UHD, Quality.FHD, Quality.HD, Quality.SD),
                        FallbackStrategy.lowerQualityOrHigherThan(Quality.SD));

Recorder.Builder recorderBuilder = new Recorder.Builder()
                        .setExecutor(getExecutor())
                        .setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
                        .setTargetVideoEncodingBitRate(50000000);

mRecorder = recorderBuilder.build();
videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(mRecorder);

UseCaseGroup useCaseGroup = new UseCaseGroup.Builder()
                            .addUseCase(videoCapture)
                            .build();

// Attach use cases to the camera with the same lifecycle owner
Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle((LifecycleOwner) this, cameraSelector, useCaseGroup);
```